# Is there a similar thing in Android to WPF's Imagebrush?

Tags: android, kotlin, rect, imagebrush

I would like to fill each Rect with a small unique image. Is there a best way to do this? Right now they are drawn with using a Paint object.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question for future reference then. Kotlin doesn't have the exact same solution, but you can draw bitmaps into rects similar to this way:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(image, Rect(0, 0, image!!.width, image!!.height), rect, null)
```